# deploying whatsapp bot in heroku not working

Tags: python, heroku, twilio, bots

I tried to build a simple whatsapp bot which will give me new google meet links when it is asked for and will provide me random jokes and memes. So the random jokes segment is working fine but the meeting link generating part is causing all the problems .I have used selenium to automate browser and divert me the link and saved the below code to a separate file and imported it to the main file. I have done same thing with the jokes management part, in the jokes management segment I have used dialogflow and twilio .This is the code for generating links from google meet which is not working:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver 

def replya():

    op = webdriver.Chromedriver
    op.binary_location = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN")
    op.add_argumnet("--headless")

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= os.environ.get('CHROMEDRIVER_PATH'),chrome_options=op)
    driver.implicitly_wait(20)
    driver.get("https://meet.google.com/")

    #clicking the meeting tab

    Tosignin=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#page-content > section.module-hero.glue-mod-spacer-6-top.glue-mod-spacer-6-bottom.hero > div > div:nth-child(1) > div.primary-meet-cta.hero-cta >div>a > button')

    Tosignin.click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)

    #to sign in
    password = "Will be managing this part later"
    email= "Will be managing this part later"
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierId"]').send_keys(email)
    driver.find_element_by_id('identifierNext').click()

    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input').send_keys(password)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="passwordNext"]/div/button/div[2]').click()

    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="yDmH0d"]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/span/span').click()

    url=driver.current_url

    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
    return url
```

I have deployed the app in heroku(size=200.3mib of 500 mib) and there I have added chrome driver in the build pack, add configured required values and keys for driver and also updated the requirements file respectively, still the app is only responding when asked for jokes .This is the main code:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse

from utils import fetch_reply           #replying with jokes
from automeetlinkgen import replya      #replying with links

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "ARTGOBLIN!"

@app.route("/sms", methods=['POST'])
def sms_reply():
"""Respond to incoming calls with a simple text message."""
    # Fetch the message
    msg = request.form.get('Body')
    phone_no=request.form.get('From')



    if msg=="meet":
        reply=replya()

    else:
        reply= fetch_reply(msg,phone_no)

    # Create reply
    resp = MessagingResponse()
    resp.message(reply)

    return str(resp)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are there any error messages you can share? Can you confirm that `replya()` is being called?

Comment: Sir, I tried to build a whatsapp bot which will respond me with random jokes and random meeting links when asked .So replya()  is a separate function call where I have declared the chrome driver program to automate browser and give link accordingly. Unfortunately when I deployed the app in heroku it is not responding  and it is getting crashed repeatedly.

Comment: have you figured out where the problem happening? is it working on the localhost?